# Wait untill firebase finish uploading to the database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have tried on completion listener , but i want to check when i press the close sesion button if there is no data left to upload, my problem is that when i press close sesion and go to my loginActivity again, data is still uploading to firebase, so i get a null error because it cant reach the user to post the last data, what i want to do is to put a listener on the close sesion button where i can check if that user id is done with uploads

```
button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {


                         Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                             @Override
                             public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
//here i want to test if the user has finished uploading all before sign out

                                 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                 mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                                 finish();
                             }
                         });



                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is it that you are uploading to Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wait untill Firebase finish uploading to the database, you need to use a [DatabaseReference.CompletionListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener).

> This interface is used as a method of being notified when an operation has been acknowledged by the Database servers and can be considered complete

This means that once your data was successfully writen on Firebase database server, then you can sign out.